# how to point parts of a single url to 2 different servers using nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have pointed a location /tanya to an address http://52.221.238.24/tanya;,
I also want /tanya/t/ to point to the same IP.

However, I need to point /tanya/dynamically_generated to point to another IP http://127.0.53.53:3000;

How is it possible using nginx.

I tried the following:

```
     location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.53.53:3000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }

    location /tanya/t/ {
            proxy_pass http://52.221.238.24/tanya/t/;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }

    location /tanya {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.53.53:3000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }

     location = /tanya/ {
            proxy_pass http://52.221.238.24/tanya;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }
```

NodeJs route:

```
     app.get('/tanya/:questionUrl',(req,res)=>{
          let ampListUrl = req.ampListBase+'/tanya/t';
          res.render('./html/questionsTanya.ejs', {
              question: question,
              ampListUrl:ampListUrl
          });
     });
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO - this is not the correct board for Administration stuff. Have a look here: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution.
Problem was, my nodeJs route was conflicting with the Nginx locations.
Solution : I created another subdir for my nodeJs route. It seems something like the following:

Nginx config :

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.53.53:3000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }

     location /tanya/t/ {
            proxy_pass http://52.221.238.24/tanya/t/;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }

    location /tanya/amp/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.53.53:3000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }
    location /tanya {
            proxy_pass http://52.221.238.24/tanya;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     }
```

Apparently, Nginx lookup for the LONGEST location uri first. As a result, it first looks up for either of "/tanya/amp/" and "/tanya/t/" and points to their respective IPs.

If none of them ("/amp" or "/t") are queried, it looks up "/tanya/anyting else" and points to IP pointed at "/tanya" location.

I thus made another change in my route (nodeJs) :

```
     app.get('/tanya/amp/:questionUrl',(req,res)=>{
      let ampListUrl = req.ampListBase+'/tanya/t';
      res.render('./html/questionsTanya.ejs', {
          question: question,
          ampListUrl:ampListUrl
      });
 });
```